# Slony Error, Replication Postgres - Slonik : PGRES_FATAL_ERROR load '$libdir/slony1_funcs.2.2.0

Tags: windows, postgresql, replication, suse, slony

So Far I have Done Slony Replication For Postrong in a single computer Successfully (Both Master and Slave Resides in Same Computer i.e. localhost).

I have done in Ubuntu 12.04, Suse Enterprise server 11, and Windows.
I followed example steps from this Links. **http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7834?page=0,0 and [this](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=17&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDQQFjAGOAo&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwiki.postgresql.org%2Fimages%2Fb%2Fbc%2FPG_Replication_on_Win.doc&ei=HlwpVMGmA8LmuQSy4YCoBA&usg=AFQjCNF_OOPgNSsB2Yni25wry9YW9V4Glw&bvm=bv.76247554,d.c2E)**

I was even able to perform this steps between two different windows computer master ip : 192.168.0.3 Slave ip 192.168.0.8)

But when I tried Slony Replication between Windows and Suse (**Master: Windows(192.168.0.3)** and **Slave:Suse(192.168.0.9)**)
when i run **slonik C:\Slony\mtscript.txt** , I got this Error

**C:\Slony\mtscript.txt:8: PGRES_FATAL_ERROR load '$libdir/slony1_funcs.2.2.0';  - ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/slony1_funcs.2.2.0": No such file or directory**

**C:\Slony\mtscript.txt:8: Error: the extension for the Slony-I C functions cannot be loaded in database 'dbname=repdb_slave host=192.168.0.9 port=5432 user=postgres password=root'**

When i googled for this error i dint found much, I just came to know that by ruining command ./pg_config i found that,

(1)in windows **slony1_funcs.2.2.0.dll** is in **LIBDIR = C:/PROGRA~2/POSTGR~1/9.3/lib**   (i.e C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.3\lib)

(2)and in Suse **slony1_funcs.2.2.0.so** is in **PKGLIBDIR = /opt/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib/postgresql**

**EDIT :**

**My Script File : mtscript.txt**

```
cluster name = repdb_cluster_suse;
node 1 admin conninfo = 'dbname=repdb host=192.168.0.3 port=5432 user=postgres password=root';
node 2 admin conninfo = 'dbname=repdb_slave host=192.168.0.9 port=5432 user=postgres password=root';
init cluster (id = 1, comment = 'Node 1');
create set (id = 1, origin = 1,comment = 'contact table');
set add table (set id = 1, origin = 1, id = 1,full qualified name = 'public.contact',comment = 'Table contact');
set add sequence (set id = 1, origin = 1, id = 2,full qualified name = 'public.contact_seq',comment = 'Sequence contact_seq');
store node (id = 2, comment = 'Node 2',event node=1);
store path (server = 1, client = 2,conninfo = 'dbname=repdb host=192.168.0.3 port=5432 user=postgres password=root');
store path (server = 2, client = 1,  conninfo = 'dbname=repdb_slave host=192.168.0.9 port=5432 user=postgres password=root');
store listen (origin = 1, provider = 1, receiver = 2);
store listen (origin = 2, provider = 2, receiver = 1);
```

I have installed same version of Postgres(Version 9.3.5.1) and slony(2.2.0-1).(both downloaded for from [**here**](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload#windows) 32 bit version)

Windows Postgres Installation Directory is  C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.3

suse Postgres install Directory is   /opt/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin

**So How to Solve this Error? How to perform Slony replication between windows and linux(suse)?**

any help wold be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like it's the linux end of things. You have checked that the file is there, so check that user postgres can access it.

Comment: yes slony1_funcs.2.2.0.so is there at /opt/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib/postgresql, infact I just now tried same thing from Ubuntu computer to Suse computer and  it worked fine, It just that windows computer is not able to perform with Suse

Comment: OK, Good. (1) Show your script (at least up to line 8) and (2) check for something tricky like line-ending / character-encoding issues.

Comment: @RichardHuxton : PLease find the EDIT in my question i have shown my complete script file. (FYI : I am using same script file for ubuntu and other computer also with change in ip address in conninfo )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Richard Huxton , that i found out my problem, according to him load 'slony1_funcs.2.2.0'; give me an error both in windows and linux and then i realize that my Slony version are different, in Windows, Version was 2.2.0 and in   linux it was 2.2.2, (got different Slony version in  Stackbuilder of Postgres 9.3 for windows and linux )

So I Un-install Slony 2.2.2 from linux and manually builded and installed  Slony 2.2.0 For Suse Linux.

And now Windows <==> Linux Slony Replication Works fine.

Answer (score 1):

OK - there's nothing obviously wrong with your setup script, and we know it works for Windows<=>Windows and Linux<=>Linux.

From your windows machine, can you try something like:

```
C:> psql -h 192.168.0.9 -U postgres -d repdb_slave
postgres# load 'foo';
postgres# load 'slony1_funcs.2.2.0';
```

The first one should give an error, and the second one should work. If not, check the pg_config settings and file location and permissions again.

Also - check the PostgreSQL server logs. If you don't see the first error logged there, make sure you are logging errors with database and user-name and try again. Then you can try slony again and just check it's doing what we think it is.

If the second "load" does work, then it might be a bug in slony itself (something to do with line-endings or similar).  They have mailing-lists mentioned on http://slony.info and I would take this problem there, giving a link to this question.

There must be plenty of people who have done cross-platform replication, so it strikes me as odd that there'd be such an obvious bug in Slony. I can't see what we're missing though.

Comment: RichardHuxton , thanks your inputs really helped me solving slony version error.